# Video chat IOS/Android Webrtc. GoogleWebRTC exampes

Tags: android, swift, webrtc

I have android video chat app using android pristine `libjingle` from 2015.
Now I need to create the same app for IOS. I consider to use the newest pod 'GoogleWebRTC'. The question is - will there be problems to communicate between android/IOS users because of older Webrtc version in android app?

I also cannot find any good GoogleWebRTC example. There is more examples and information about how to use the oldest pristine `libjingle` both in IOS and android.

Signaling does not work as i hoped.

update 31/08/2018

[Failed to set remote video description send parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019677/failed-to-set-remote-video-description-send-parameters-iphone-android)

Comment: Can not get over the errors by doing signaling. Can not set succesfully remote description on IPhone. May be somebody has experience with this?

Comment: so have u got ur answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the source code in github:https://github.com/webrtc/samples

and http://psrd.it

Comment: I need IOS examples and answers on  question (update 31/08/2018)