# Understanding how to generate correct sdp for offer/answer (webrtc) between android/Iphone

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, webrtc

I am struggling to understand the correct way to make correct offer answer when signaling is between Iphone and android phone. Because of different codecs Iphone setRemoteDescription is failing. As known android does not accept H264.

> (Failed to set remote video description send parameters)

Between android/android all working fine because both phones have equal VP8/9 codecs. But in my case IOS is sending to android sdp offer with ONLY H264 codec. So appearently that is the problem. Despite that android is setting remotedescription and afterher creates answer with sdp without VP8/9 codec info. This answer sdp is setting Iphone with above mentioned error. So i am asking why in android answer sdp is no line with VP8/9 or any codec.
You can see offers and answer sdps in this question (
[offer and answer sdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019677/failed-to-set-remote-video-description-send-parameters-iphone-android)).
So i try to init PeerconnectionFactory following way

```
    let decoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory.init()
    let encoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory.init()
    let videoCodedInfo = RTCVideoCodecInfo.init(name: kRTCVideoCodecVp8Name )
    encoderFactory.preferredCodec = videoCodedInfo        
    let connectionFactory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory.init(encoderFactory: encoderFactory, decoderFactory: decoderFactory)
```

But even i use such initialization sdp offers and answers does not changes. So where is the problem and how i can create correct sdp for android/Ios so the setremotedescription does not show error.

I have android app using libjingle from 2015 and for IOS app GoogleWebRTC pod from 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let decoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory()
let encoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory()
factory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory(encoderFactory: encoderFactory, decoderFactory: decoderFactory)
```

I use https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC in IOS.
This worked for me when call with Android 4.x, video type is VP8 and when call with IOS video is H264.
Hope for you

Comment: That does not help for me. The same error. In answer sdp is no info about codec v8. Very strange.

Comment: At Android i use https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/ . I connected both VP8 and H264 for android and IOS.

Comment: U can try use only source of Google, not use source of anyone. Because they has convert only to VP8.

Comment: I cant change cource for android. Android app is using android pristine libjingle from 2015 from google. But for IOS i use latest pod 'GoogleWebRTC'. I am not sure they are conflicting because of different release years. GoogleWebRTC is continuation of pristine libjingle. There are the same methods for WebRtc and partly the same code. I can only try to downgrade GoogleWebRTC to  pristine libjingle for IOS and check how it works. But i am not sure should i do that?

Comment: will try to upgrade my android from  libjingle to compile 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'

Comment: How do You init PeerConnectionFactory in android?

Comment: You can try https://cocoapods.org/pods/WebRTC for IOS, this will connected to android, but this only use VP8, not use H264. This makes iphone so hot.

Comment: For ios i use pod GoogleWebRTC.  Is that something different?

Comment: yes. with WebRTC this media only convert VP8, this means it connected with all android. you can try it

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the google-webrtc version problem. but i don't know why.   you should not use the 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'.   you can try a proper version, like  'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24277'